# Running php code within WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg

I got the execPHP plug in installed. no problems with it as far as executing the php code thru the editor... for example, I tried the following the PHP snippet within the WYSIWYG editor and it works...

```
[?php echo get_post_meta(1717, 'Ref', true); ?]
```

it outputs the value stored within the custom field titled REF. And the 1717 happens to be the current post id of the post I was editing.

here is the question...

whenever I tried to access post related data ( usually available in the wordpress loop ), nothing gets outputted. for example, the following produces nothing...

```
[?php echo ("postid=" . $post->ID ); ?]
```

Within the WYSIWYG editor, even the the_ID() outputs nothing. I thought, we were still in the wordpress loop and I could tap into any post related data at the moment.

my goal was to replace the `[?php echo get_post_meta(1717, 'Ref', true); ?]` with `[?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ref', true); ?]`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the wordpress function `get_the_ID()` instead of accessing the $post variable.
I guess you can access $post also if you put global $post

Comment: thanks but it did not help. [?php 
$mypostid = get_the_ID(); 
echo ( "mypostid:" . $mypostid);
?] outputs nothing!

Comment: Nothing ? or just mypostid:  ?

Comment: just mypostid: string gets outputted. that's because it is in the quotes. the variable part (the $mypostid part ) outputs nothing. so all I end up getting is the following; mypostid:

Comment: It seems the execPHP plugin is not executing in the loop. Can you try following <?php $this_page_id = $wp_query->post->ID; echo $this_page_id ;?>

Comment: thanks but noo.. i did this [?php 
$this_page_id = $wp_query->post->ID; 
echo "after wp_query .... " . $this_page_id ;
?] and i get this at the end after wp_query ….